# How to style an img width if the following element is an img?

Tags: css, sass, styles

I have a problem. I want to detect if an img is followed by an img in scss and style these img with a specific width. PS : I don't know where is the image or anything, I fetch data from an API, the following code is just an example

```
<div class='article'>
  <h1 />
  <img />
  <img />
  <p></p>
  <img />
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

if image is followed by an image I want to style just these two image width, but I don't know how to style an element if this condition is respected. I need help, thanks you :)

Comment: In CSS it's not possible to style an element based on what children or siblings it has. But you could use javascript to make that search query. Also, please include your code in your question.

Comment: Please share your HTML in the question.